# php variables search in another file

Tags: php

Here is the code im working with as of now

```
 <?php

 $url = 'http://www.PULLDATADOMAIN.Com/Here'; 
 $Stuff = 'Wow im not a complete idiot';
 $After = 'This is not what im doing';

 $contents = file_get_contents($url);
 echo $contents; 


?>
```

Okay as of right now this is quite raw. All it is doing is pulling the html source code from the $url and displaying it on the page.

But what I am looking to have it do is pull that html and then search for where it finds the variable $After

And then output / echo the first half of the $contents then output `$mystuff` then out put the second half of `$contents`.

Comment: What exactly you want to do from that HTMl ? Can you please explain coz question is not clear...

Comment: If you are getting all html, if you cut the result into multiple there are chance to break the page.

Comment: Where you want to use this content ? in html page or somewhere in the apllication ?

Comment: Are you trying to parse php with php?  There's a construct called `include`

Comment: Where is `if` statement here ? `HTML If` !!!!

Comment: So basically you want the output to be $After + first half of contents + $stuff
Am I correct?

Comment: I want it to out put $ContentFirstHalf + $Stuff + $ContentSecondHalf

And yes Sahal that would work how do I do a content cut or break on that contents variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

$url = 'https://www.google.com/roboat.txt';

$Stuff = 'Life is good when we get help on time';

$After = '/The service you requested is not available at this time/';

$contents = file_get_contents($url);

$result = preg_split($After,$contents);

print_r($result);

Comment: Warning: preg_split() [function.preg-split]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /home/content/34/9587634/html/MYDOMAIN on line 9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288188/php-preg-split-error-when-switching-from-split-to-preg-split

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to achieve is not very difficult. You should mention what methods you have tried so far.

I am not going to give you the solution but will only give you hint.

Step 1) 
You can use **strpos** function to find the position of your **$stuff** string and then use **substr** function to extract only first half of the **$contents**

Step 2)
Then you can append the new string you want **$mystuff**

Step 3) Now again using the position found in step 1 and **substr** function and **strlen** for length of searched string **$stuff** you can print the second half.

Comment: hey I was able to get it thank you very much

Comment: @PaigePare I expect you to select this answer or at-least vote if it helped.